# Js background color changer

Tags: javascript

Each square has a random color. For example, pink becomes green, orange becomes pink etc.How can I change the backgrounds?

```
<section>
    <div id="one"></div>
    <div id="two"></div>
    <div id="three"></div>
    <div id="four"></div>
    <button id="btn">Click Me</button>
</section>




  let colors = ["pink" , 'yellow' , 'green' , 'blue']
let btn = document.getElementById('btn')
let one = document.getElementById('one')
let two = document.getElementById('two')
let three = document.getElementById('three')
let four = document.getElementById('four')

one.style.backgroundColor = colors[0]
two.style.backgroundColor = colors[1]
three.style.backgroundColor = colors[2]
four.style.backgroundColor = colors[3]

btn.addEventListener('click' , function(){
    let randomColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]

    one.style.backgroundColor = randomColor

})
```

and then i cant understand what to do

Comment: Any Javascript you have tried so far?

Comment: yes I add the code

Comment: can i see some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one instead which is easier by using `forEach` loop.

Use `unshift` to move the last element to the top of the array every time user clicks it.

```js
let colors = ["pink" , 'yellow' , 'green' , 'blue']
//Assign orginial color:
document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach((item,index)=>{
item.style.backgroundColor = colors[index]
})
document.querySelector('#btn').addEventListener("click",function(){
document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach((item,index)=>{
item.style.backgroundColor = colors[index]
})
colors.unshift(colors.splice(colors.length-1, 1)[0]);
})
```

```html
<div id="one">1</div>
    <div id="two">2</div>
    <div id="three">3</div>
    <div id="four">4</div>
    <button id="btn">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: Thansk you so much. But how can i do this? when I click on the button the squares change their colors. For example, pink becomes green, orange becomes pink ,blue becomes orange ?

Comment: @BegginerJS, so you want them to change sequencely not randomly?

Comment: yes sequencely not randomly

Comment: @BegginerJS, update the code. Check it now! I doesn't change the color, but I think as long as you have the code, it is very easy:)

Comment: Thanks you so much @James .Please can you explain how it works?I am beginner in JS

Comment: @BegginerJS, are you confused with the `forEach` or `unshift`?

Comment: yes with them.I cant understand that.

Comment: @BegginerJS, for the `forEach`, the `item` refers to an individual div (eg. div[0],div[1] every loop from all three div, a good suggestion is to check [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) since I cant explain it pretty well.

Comment: @BegginerJS,   In term of the unshift, `The unshift() method adds one or more elements to the beginning of an array and returns the new length of the array.`, I use splice to splice the array except the last one and add finally add the last element in the arrat to the top. You could check it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) Does this solve  your confusion?

Comment: what is this? Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.